# Activating blocks of code with [#define & #ifdef] cross-file

Tags: c++

I don't know what this concept is called, so title may sound weird. Imagine the following scenario:

main.cpp:

```
#define SOME_KEYWORD

int main() 
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

other.cpp:

```
void foo()
{
    //Do some stuff

#ifdef SOME_KEYWORD
    //Do some additional stuff
#endif
}
```

I've tried it out and it doesn't work if `#define` is present in other file. Is there a way around this? (I'd rather not to modify function parameters just to achieve this, since it will only be present at development time and functions can be many layers of abstraction away.)

And, I guess this is a C way to do things, I don't know if that would be considered as a good practice in C++, if not, what are the alternative ways?

Comment: Put `#define SOME_KEYWORD` into a header file and include that header in both source files. Or set a compiler command line option.

Comment: Also, what you are doing is called ["conditional compilation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation)

Comment: Avoid macros if you can. In this case, you could use `constexpr if`.

Comment: @cigien, `if constexpr` cannot do everything that `#ifdef` can do. If its not a template, then the code still gets compiled, which can cause compilation errors …

Comment: @ChrisMM True, but seems to be ok for the OP's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++, from c++17, a [`constexpr-if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) would be a good way to go about doing this. e.g. in some header file:

```
// header.hpp
#pragma once
constexpr bool choice = true;  // or false, if you don't want to compile some additional stuff
```

and in an implementation file:

```
#include "header.hpp"
void foo()
{
    //Do some stuff

    if constexpr(choice)
    {
       //Do some additional stuff
    }
}
```

Note that is not a drop in replacement for `#define`, but it works in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what this concept is called

Generally, pre-processing. More specifically, the pre-processor is used here to conditionally compile the program.

This a common technique that is used to create portable interfaces over platform specific ones. Sometimes it is used to enable or suppress debugging features.

> I've tried it out and it doesn't work if #define is present in other file.

Macros only affect the file where they are defined.

> Is there a way around this?

Define the macro in all of the files where you use it. Typically, this is achieved by including the definition from a header, or by specifying a compiler option.

> And, I guess this is a C way to do things, I don't know if that would be considered as a good practice in C++, if not, what are the alternative ways?

There is no complete alternative in C++. In some cases they can be replaced or combined with templates and `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

A preprocessor symbol defined in one translation unit is not visible in a different translation unit. As suggested in a comment you can define it in a header and then include where needed (its not a keyword, so I chose a better name):

```
// defines.h
#define SOME_SYMBOL      

// other.cpp
#include "defines.h
```

Conditional compilation via preprocessor macros has some uses, eg conditionally compiling platform specific code or excluding debug code from release builds. For anything else I would not use it, because when overused it can create a big mess and is error-prone (eg too easy to forget to include `defines.h`). Consider to make `foo` a template:

```
template <bool SOME_FLAG>
void foo()
{
    //Do some stuff

   if constexpr (SOME_FLAG) {
       //Do some additional stuff
   }
}
```

And if you still want to make use of the preprocessor, this allows you to concentrate usage of macros to a single location:

```
// main.cpp
#define SOME_SYMBOL
#ifdef SOME_SYMBOL
constexpr bool flag = true;
#else
constexpr bool flag = false;

int main() 
{
    foo<flag>();
    return 0;
}
```